# internal server error connecting to Aurora

Tags: api, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.1, amazon-aurora, aws-serverless

In VS 2017 I created a AWS Serverless Application (.NET Core - C#). I have a RDS (Aurora) with data in it.

I added MySql.Data to the project using NuGet. 
Created a new controller to get the data out of the DB.
Created a method and model to Get data.
Built the project and ran it locally in VS.

I was able to use Postman to Get data from the API. GREAT!

Right clicked the project and selected Publish to AWS Lambda. Everything published and got the new URL.

when using the url/api/method. I get a 500 return. Tried another Controller that just returns values with no DB queries and that works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is check the CloudWatch logs for your function for the source of the error (as 500 indicates an Internal Server Error i.e. your code throws an exception). Add logging into your function as needed if you don't get anything useful there.

Access control is one likely candidate. Is your database accessible from your lambda and does the deployed function correctly receive the database credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see anything in the Cloud Watch, unfortunately. I thought that it will create it automatically when I published with AWS. Everything works locally. My aurora is public so I'm not sure what other permissions I need